# What is the correct name of this type of switch

Tags: switches, latch

new here so be kind. What or how do I make a toggle switch stay on as long as current is flowing through it and toggle to off once it stops. I did try all sorts of naming searches in google but came up with nothing.

So for example 24vdc --- turn switch on ----- load  24vdc stops switch toggles to off poistion.

I hope this is clear and thank you in advance

Comment: An SCR kind of works that way. You could have a momentary button fire the SCR after which it will conduct until the current drops below some threshold. In general, the requirement to detect the zero current condition, and open the circuit in response, is fairly complex for a switch. Another circuit that may be of interest is the magnetic latching circuit used in some power tools. It stays on until either you turn it off, or until power is removed (due to a circuit breaker or something).

Comment: Personally I'd call it a latching switch, but that might be miss-interpreted as a "push-push" switch or of the like.

Answer (score 1):

It's a thyristor that is used in the DC circuit.

[image]

And a triac in the AC version.

[image]

'ON' / 'Off' control is through the 'NO' / 'NC' contacts of two momentary push button switches.

Answer (score 0):

There is no off-the-shelf switch that performs that way.  You can achieve the same result with a momentary switch (pushbutton, toggle, whatever) controlling a small latching circuit, with a p-channel power MOSFET switching + voltage to the load, or with an n-channel power MOSFET switching the return.

OR - going old school - a momentary switch and an SCR.  Note that an SCR will have a larger voltage drop across it than a MOSFET would at the same load current.

EDIT:  There is a classic circuit with a SPST momentary switch and a DPST (or DPDT) relay, where one pole forms a latch that keeps the relay coil energized after the switch opens.  From your description, this technique will not work for your application.  You need some kind of load current sensing device/circuit/function to effectively reset the power-on latch when the load current returns to zero.

Comment: For older school, use a pushbutton and a relay wired to hold itself on.

Comment: The older school relay solution is often the right answer even today if you need "bulletproof"  off condition, such as for a machine tool power that you'd like to ensure stays off if the power goes off and then is restored.

Comment: You missed something.  He wants the removal of the load to reset the latch (relay, electronic, whatever).  This means the load current must go through the relay coil or some other kind of current sensor.  I'm very familiar with the pushbutton-and-relay latch circuit.  This ain't it.  Updated my answer.